# regex - is there anyway to simplify this regex (OR)?

Tags: notepad++, regex

**the basic regex is**

```
[^ ]*KEYWORD[^ ]*
```

Keyword = freetext,

I have many many keywords, so I use OR >>> "|", and repeat the regex many times in 1 line, for example:

```
[^ ]*210[^ ]*|[^ ]*211[^ ]*|[^ ]*212[^ ]*|[^ ]*213[^ ]*|[^ ]*214[^ ]*
```

**is there a way to simply this? because when I do simulation, it took 46057 steps, it's too much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some sample text and the regex flavor (what language/tool are you using?), it's hard to know what you're trying to achieve. But, given your regex, it can be simplified like:

```
[^ ]*(?:210|211|212|213|214)[^ ]*
```

Where the construction `(?...)` is called a non capture group really more efficient than a capture group (in case where you don't need to capture the data of course).

Another simplification gives:

```
[^ ]*21[0-4][^ ]*
```

Depending on what you want to match (what are the `[^ ]*` for?), the following should be enough:

```
21[0-4]
```

Comment: I use it to delete all words in a paragraph or description, that contains 210, like abc210 or 210abc or abc210def

Comment: what language/tool are you using? >>>  I am using notepad++ and then import manual to excel. Btw, I found out how to delete and just keep the comma >>>  [^ ]*KEYWORD[^ ,]* Thank you @Toto it's very helpful

Comment: @DamarTD: You're welcome, glad it helps. For future question, please, give sample text and expected result, it will be easier to answer.